# Node.js Express Jade - Cant display leaflet map

Tags: node.js, express, leaflet, pug

Im new to this and am following a tutorial [here](http://duspviz.mit.edu/web-map-workshop/leaflet_nodejs_postgis/). I'm trying to create a map view using jade (i know its now pug but the tutorial uses jade).

I have a router request for my map page in my index.js folder. It queries a database and returns some data in geojson format. I got the data to display on a separate page so shouldnt be an issue there.

Request for map page in index.js:

```
//get map page
router.get('/map', function(req, res) {
    var client = new pg.Client(conString); // Setup our Postgres Client
    client.connect(); // connect to the client
    var query = client.query(example_query); // Run our Query
    query.on("row", function (row, result) {
        result.addRow(row);
    });
    // Pass the result to the map page
    query.on("end", function (result) {
        var data = result.rows[0].row_to_json // Save the JSON as variable data
        res.render('map', {
            title: "Express API", // Give a title to our page
            jsonData: data // Pass data to the View
        });
    });
});
```

The next step was to create a map view so I can display the data with a leaflet map. Saved in map.jade:

```
extends layout
block content
    #map
    script(src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js")
    script.
        var myData = !{JSON.stringify(jsonData)};
        // Create variable to hold map element, give initial settings to map
        var map = L.map('map',{ center: [42.375562, -71.106870], zoom: 14});
        // Add tile layer to map element
        L.tileLayer("https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/outdoors-v10/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=exampleaccesstoken", {attribution: "Mapbox", maxZoom: 18, minZoom: 2}).addTo(map);
        // Add JSON to map
        L.geoJson(myData,{
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.f2);
            }
        }).addTo(map);
```

NPM starts up fine, but when i go to view the page (localhost:3000/map), there's nothing there. No errors...nothing. The tutorial didnt include the leaflet.js script and leaflet.css link, which led to "L. not being defined". I included them but not sure if I have them in the right spot. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's layout.jade for reference:

```
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css")
  body
    div
    block content
```

And index.jade... (I didnt touch this one)

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

Comment: Have you specified a CSS `height` on your `#map` div container?

Comment: If you Inspect Element, is there anything in the page source? It might be rendering, but you just might not have any CSS to tell the map how to show (unless you inherit some CSS from leaflet.js)

Answer (score 0):

For your map.jade file, on line 3, try ensuring that your map div has its height and width specified. I'm crunching something similar with a mapbox map, and for the sake of testing, I'm defining how #map will render with the following inline style:

```
#map(style="width: 100vw; height: 500px;")
```

I wasn't able to get the mapbox tiles to render properly on my first attempt, so I used a different provider. https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/ contains a list of the known providers, many of which are free. I was able to get your example (minus the server-derived points) to render fine with a Stamen baselayer.